# DNN: How can I edit Source code of DNN blog module

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I have DNN 7.2 and I am using DNN blog module. For some reason I need to edit code from code behind file. I have installed Blog 6.0.4 source code package. I was trying to edit it from Visual studio but it won't reflect the change. Is there any way to edit source code of DNN module.

Please guide me how can I edit code behind file for DNN module. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to open the Project file in Visual Studio, then once you make changes, you will need to compile the project and ensure that the DLLs are going into the website's BIN folder.

Any changes made to the ASCX files should be visible immediately.

This all assumes you are opening the project files out of the desktopmodules/blog folder (assuming that's where the module gets installed) and not out of a folder OUTSIDE of the DNN website.

Chris

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for ur answer. I am opening Blog project files under Desktop module but I want to modify source code. So I opened blog soln file with VS2013 when when I open that it gives me Migration error.

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to look at the project properties to see which references are missing their associated DLLs and add the references back in from the version of DNN that you have on your website.